# play audio file on discord voice channel wile file is being generated

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, discord.py

I am making a discord bot that reads reddit posts with a text to speech on voice chat but the audio file has to be fully generated for the bot to begin playing so for longer posts the wait time is over 10 minutes. But the file is generated faster then you listen to it so theoretically I could make it after the text is done being downloaded it could wait 3 seconds then playing the file and the audio would work just as if the file was already generated

```
    async def on_message(self, ctx):
        if ctx.content.startswith("-p"):
            connected = ctx.author.voice
            if connected: #if the poster in conected to a voice channel
                if is_connected(self) == False: #if the bot not connected to a voice chat it will join the posters voice chat
                    global voice
                    voice = await connected.channel.connect()
                say(ctx.content.split()[1]) #uses URL of a reddit to make a mp3 file of a TTS reading the post
                player = voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("out.mp3")) #stream the auidio file to the voice channel
                player.start()
```

the `say()` function generates the the next line plays the audio

would threading be usefull

Answer (score 0):

if you want the bot to wait 3 seconds, before the file playback method use
`import time` than `time.sleep(3)` number 3 indicates the number of seconds how long the bot will wait, full code =

```
..
import time
..

    async def on_message(self, ctx):
        if ctx.content.startswith("-p"):
            connected = ctx.author.voice
            if connected: #if the poster in conected to a voice channel
                if is_connected(self) == False: #if the bot not connected to a voice chat it will join the posters voice chat
                    global voice
                    voice = await connected.channel.connect()
                say(ctx.content.split()[1]) #uses URL of a reddit to make a mp3 file of a TTS reading the post
                time.sleep(3)
                player = voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("out.mp3")) #stream the auidio file to the voice channel
                player.start()
```

Comment: He should use `asyncio` instead. Using `time.sleep` will freeze the entire program, so it will stop every command from being detected during 3 seconds. With asynchronous functions, you'll have to use `asyncio.sleep(3)`.